# Lua: Сравнение строк

Tags: linux, bash, lua

```
str    = '/home/user/test.lua'
needed = '/home/user'
handle = io.popen('dirname -z '..str)
result = handle:read('*all')

print(needed)
print(result)

if needed ~= result then
    print 'Does not work!'
end
```

Почему всегда `'Does not work!'`?

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Благодаря ответу, найден способ корректировки результата:

    `result = result:sub(0, -2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экспериментально установлено, что, строка, возвращаемая `handle:read(...)`, имеет в конце завершающий символ '\0', а `needed` - не имеет. Это разные строки.

```
print(needed:len())
print(result:len())

for i = 0, needed:len(), 1 do
    print(needed:byte(i))
end

for i = 0, result:len(), 1 do
    print(result:byte(i))
end
```